# Two random points are placed in segment $[0,a]$ ,distributed uniformly. Find pdf and cdf of distance between those points.

Tags: probability

Two random points are placed in segment $[0,a]$,distributed uniformly. Find pdf and cdf of distance between those points.

My work.

Let $Y=|X_1-X_2|$

$F(X_i) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{$X_i \leq 0$} \\
\frac{X_i}{a}, & \text{$0 < X_i \leq a$}
\end{cases}$

First need to find $F_Y=P(Y<t)=P(X_1-t<X_2<t+X_1)=F(t+X_1)-F(X_1-t)$

From here don't know how to continue. Can you help? Also please without using joint functions and if possible integrals(double) for finding $F$.

Comment: The question does not have an answer unless $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent. Without integration I don't think you can answer  this.

Comment: @geetha290krm I saw solution of this which used double integrals for joints cdf. Saying without integrals I means without using joint cdf.

Answer (score 1):

To approach this problem geometrically, consider the square $S:=\{(x,y):0<x,y<a\}$. For a given $0<t<a$, the area of the subset $A$ of $S$ where $Y:=|X_1-X_2|\leqslant t$ can be found by subtracting from $S$ the area of the two triangles which compose $S\setminus A$:
$$
a^2 - 2(a-t)^2.
$$
Dividing this area by the area of $A$, we find
$$
F_Y(t)=\mathbb P(Y|\leqslant t) = 1-\left(1-\frac ta\right)^2.
$$
The density $f_Y$ of $Y$ is obtained by differentiating the above with respect to $t$:
$$
\frac{\mathsf d}{\mathsf dt}F_Y(t) = \frac{2(a-t)}{a^2}.
$$